# Number of solutions for a trigonometric equation based on $\sin x+\cos x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\textbf{Question : }$ Find the number of solutions for the following equation for $x \in [0,100\pi]$ $$(\sin x +\cos x +2)^4=128\sin 2x$$

$\textbf{My Attempt :}$

As $(\sin x +\cos x)^2=1+\sin 2x$, let  $\sin x + \cos x =z \implies  z \in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ then
$$(z+2)^4=128(z^2-1)$$
which simplifies to the following
$$f(z) = z^4 + 8 z^3 - 104 z^2 + 32 z + 144 $$
Now we can clearly see that
$$f(-1),f(0),f(1)>0 $$
$$f(2),f(-2) <0$$
so we have two real roots for sure but now how to check for the other two roots or is there a better method to this problem altogether...

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the quartic equation
$$ z^4 + 8 z^3 - 104 z^2 + 32 z + 144=0$$ using (awful) radicals.

On the other hand, solving
$$(2+\sin (x)+\cos (x))^4-128 \sin (2 x)=0$$is the same as solving
$$88 \sin (x)-204 \sin (2 x)+8 \sin (3 x)+88 \cos (x)-8 \cos (3
   x)-\cos (4 x)+83=0$$ which,, for $x \in (0,2\pi)$, by inspection (take into account the size of the coefficients) has roots close to $\pi$ and $\frac {3\pi}2$. I suppose that this is sufficient to conclude.

**Off topic**

If you want to have *approximate* solutions of the equation, use Taylor series around the locations

$$2-520 (x-\pi )+16 (x-\pi )^2+O\left((x-\pi )^3\right)$$
and
$$2+520 \left(x-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right)+16 \left(x-\frac{3 \pi
   }{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right)^3\right)$$

Neglecting the higher order terms, solving the quadratics give
$$x_1 \sim \pi+\frac{65-\sqrt{4223}}{4}=\color{red}{3.1454392}63\cdots$$
$$x_2 \sim \frac{3 \pi }{2}-\frac{65-\sqrt{4223}}{4}=\color{red}{4.7085423}71\cdots$$ while the "exact" solutions are
$$x_1=3.145439298\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=4.708542336$$

Answer (score 2):

Other solutions to the quartic are approximately $z=-15$ and $z=7$, therefore cannot be equal to $\sin x+\cos x$.

To see whether the solutions you have already are possible, you need to check the sign of $f(z)$ at $z=\pm\sqrt2$.

Comment: What is the period of $~z~?$

Comment: $f(\sqrt{2})>0$ and $f(-\sqrt{2})<0$ so only one solution in $z \in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: @David how did you approximate the roots did you just brute forced calculate $f(-15)$ and $f(-7)$ and other neighbouring points or something else which would subside the immense calculation

Comment: @sparrow_2764 I drew a graph with Maple.